# Shutdown  does not depower

Tags: 12.04, hardware

When shutting down in 12.04, either in terminal or GUI, the result is a laptop (dell inspiron M4300) which is still powered. I then have to hold the power button for 5 seconds to depower. It's just an annoyance, but an annoyance i wouldn't mind getting to the bottom of. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please try the boot parameters `noacpi` OR `acpi=force`. It's usually an ACPI incompatibility of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

Modify `/etc/modules` and add:

```
 apm power_off=1
```

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and add this after quiet splash:

```
acpi=force apm=power_off
```

Finally update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```